# HTML: two <p> and one <div> tag in same line problems

Tags: html

I am trying to do like this:

[image: Rate example]

This is my html code:

```
<p>' + $(this).text() + '<p>Rate<div id="betygbox"></div></p></p>
```

I cant be able to make  them show on one line

I have tried to put them all in one div tag with `display: inline;` But it aint working.
Is there easy solutions to get it all in one line?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<p>` tags shouldn't be nested, so that's part of the problem. Try this instead:

```
'<p>' + $(this).text() + '<span>Rate<span id="betygbox"></span></span></p>
```

Comment: Assuming `Rate: [    ]` is to be right aligned, don't forget to add `span { float: right }` to your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1), **The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).** So, your HTML is not valid.

Comment: How can I do it then like my image?

Comment: I don't know which layout exactly you are aiming for, but supposing that you want to left-align all the edit fields, you can use table layout, similar to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYFrb/). If you need all the fields right-aligned, use JamWaffles' comment on another answer.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is not allowed inside `<p>`.

Read html-specifications.